# how to use $_GET a html href=?asd

Tags: php

I have a html view what contains an input text and textarea. I've made a SQL query that gives back a link `<a href="?asd">$row['title']</a>`.

I'd like make a method where if I click the link, I load to in the html view.

```
if(isset($_GET['asd'])){//load to view}
```

I don't know how can I do this.

Here is the view:

```
public function note($title,$text){
    ?>
    <html>
    <head><title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="view/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="forms">
    <form action="" method="post" class="style-1">
        <input type="text" name="note_title" value='<?php echo $title?>'><br>
        <input type="text" name="note_text" value='<?php echo $text?>'><br>
        <input type="submit" name="sendNote" value="Save">
        <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">


    </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>

    <?php

}
```

The link:

```
echo "<u><a href='?editnote'>".$title."</a></u>";
```

Load to view:

```
if(isset($_GET['editnote'])){
      $id = $_SESSION['loggedInUser'];
      $title =  $model->getNameToSession("note","user_id",$id, 'title');
      $text =  $model->getNameToSession("note","user_id",$id, 'text');


      $view->note($title,$text);
```

But I don't know how to load the sql result to view. I think my link is wrong, I read about `href ans $_GET` and I saw this: `<a href="something.php?id=$row['id']">`, but I don't know how I'd use it.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You to load each view use key/value pair e.g. view=editnote

```
echo "<u><a href='?view=editnote'>".$title."</a></u>";
```

Load the view

```
if( isset( $_GET['view'] ) && $_GET['view'] === 'editnote' ){
```

Use the vars in the view, add a semicolon each php statement

```
 <form action="" method="post" class="style-1">
        <input type="text" name="note_title" value='<?php echo $title; ?>'><br>
        <input type="text" name="note_text" value='<?php echo $text; ?>'><br>
</form>
```