# How to make URL change content of a website?

Tags: php, url

Hope you'll be able to help me, as I searched all around Google with various keywords and couldn't find anything relevant to me, or I just don't know what this thing I'm curios about is called.

I have a website, which I want to be personalized, according to the URL string.
So I'd link to send my friend a link like http://example.com/index.php?name=Joanna and it would change the beggining of my page to "Hi Joanna!". I just want it to be simple as that and integrate it into PHP or HTML (which is easier), but don't know how to achieve that.

Any help would be appreciated :)

P.S. - Keep the "How you don't know that?" remarks away , I'm new at this and am still learning.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852424/correct-syntax-for-hyperlink-url-with-php-get - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497892/how-to-use-get-a-html-href-asd

Comment: Thanks - as said, I couldn't find the right thing as I didn't know what it was called :)

Comment: You're welcome, and *Welcome to Stack*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**See [HTTP GET Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)**

If your URL is

```
www.example.com/index.php?name=Joanna
```

it means that `$_GET["name"]` is "Joanna".

So in PHP, you can output:

```
<?php echo "Hi ".$_GET["name"]."!"; ?>
```

and it will output, in this case:

> Hi Joanna!

---

You can also check that the variable exists and isn't empty by doing one of the following:

```
isset($_GET["name"]) //will return true even if $_GET==""
!empty($_GET["name"])
$_GET["name"]!=""
```

So you can change your PHP output to:

```
if(!empty($_GET["name"])){
    $name = $_GET["name"];
} else {
    $name = "guest";
}

echo "Hi, ".$name."!";
```

which will output "guest" if `$_GET["name"]` is empty.

Shorter version of the above:

```
echo "Hi, ".(empty($_GET["name"]) ? "guest" : $_GET["name"])."!";
```

Comment: while adding a conditional statement to check if it is set/not empty.

Comment: Right you are - see amedments

Comment: Thanks to you both! It works as a charm :)

Comment: @HarisMustajbasic Glad to have been of help, *cheers*